# What is the purpose of single-line statements in python?

Tags: python, syntax

I am aware that multiple lines in python that are part of a conditional statement can be reduced into a single line.

For example:

```
if foo == 'bar':
   do_one()
   do_two()
   do_three()
```

Can be reduced down to:

```
if foo == 'bar': do_one(); do_two(); do_three()
```

But what are the advantages of such a syntax apart from the obvious fact that it takes up fewer lines of code?

*e.g. Is it more memory efficient?*

Is not the standard syntax much more readable for the average Python user?

Comment: Apart from enabling one-liners on the CLI (e.g. `$ python -c 'foo; bar; baz'`), simply "it should not be *impossible* to do one-liners, just very very discouraged"…?

Comment: No, it’s not more memory efficient. It’s literally the same thing in less vertical space.

Comment: You cannot collapse arbitrary code onto one line; you can't, for instance, write an `if` statement in the body of an `if` statement on one line: `if True: if True: print("hi")` is a syntax error.

Comment: @chepner on that note ternary expressions, on the other hand, e.g. `i = 2 if a > 5 else 0` are possible.

Comment: @deceze so it serves no advantages whatsoever to anyone, but only exists so that it should not be impossible to do so?

Comment: Again, I’d guess that the main purpose is to make Python more useful in contexts like the CLI with short one-off scripts.

Comment: @Newbie123 My comment was made because I didn't notice you were using the phrase "compound statement" to refer to your single-line `if` statement. A compound statement has a precise meaning in Python: it's the class of statements including, among other things, `if` statements, `while` and `for` loops, and function/class definitions. Generally speaking, the body of a compound statement is either a single *simple* statement (on the same line or indented on the following line) or a series of simple statements on the following lines, all indented equally. ...

Comment: ... A simple statement is one or more *small* statements, joined by semicolons. A small statement are roughly those statements that do one thing, rather than allowing a multiline "continuation" as a body. See the [grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) for more details.

Comment: If Python's grammar were being defined today, with the benefit of hindsight, I'm not convinced that simple statements would be included. Every statement would be a small statement or a compound statement consisting of small statements; no semicolons in sight. (And the only thing allowed after the `:` on the first line of a compound statement would be whitespace or comments; no small statements to complete them.)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there are no advantages of compound statements. It is actually even worse to do that as it make your code less readable. In most cases you write your code so that it is easy for humans to read it rather than to make it too complicated or short.

You can find some more infromation [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/104066/single-line-statements-good-practices)